# How to construct URL from an initial URL python

Tags: python

I'm trying to construct a URL based on what I get from a initial URL.

Example:

*URL1:*

```
http://some-url/rest/ids?configuration_path=project/Main/10-deploy
```

**Response here is** 123

*URL2:*

```
http://abc-bld/download/{RESPONSE_FROM_URL1_HERE}.latest_successful/artifacts/build-info.props
```

so my final URL will be:

```
http://tke-bld/download/123.latest_successful/artifacts/build-info.props
```

**Response here is** Some.Text.here.123

Then I'd like to grab 'Some.Text.here.123' and store it in a variable.

How can I accomplish this with python?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are doing simple HTTP GET requests, you can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library

Something like

```
import requests
initial_request = requests.get('http://request1.com/something')
value = request1.text

second_request = requests.get('http://request2.com/value={0}'.format(value))
response = second_request.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and some *string formatting*, something along these lines:

```
import requests

initial_url = "http://some-url/rest/ids"
initial_url_params = {
    "configuration_path": "project/Main/10-deploy"
}
with requests.Session() as session:
     response = session.get(initial_url, params=initial_url_params)

     second_url = "http://abc-bld/download/{0}.latest_successful/artifacts/build-info.props".format(response.content)

     response = session.get(second_url)
     print(response.content)
```